# How can I pass a dynamic array as Input() from the component template?

Tags: angular

This issue is as good as this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38178280/how-can-i-pass-an-array-as-input-from-the-component-template?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) but i need the array as dynamic!

**FileName**: app.component.html

```
<ques [card_title]="'Abc'" [card_text]="'What is Space'" [items]="{{items}}"></ques>

<ques [card_title]="'Xyz'" [card_text]="'What is Time'" [items]="{{items}}"></ques>
```

"ques selector is from an external component which has items array".
I am currently in app module where i have imported the ques component and now i need to pass an array to the ques!

What currently works is

**FileName**: app.component.html

```
<ques [card_title]="'Abc'" [card_text]="'What is Space'" [items]="['google','stack','overflow']"></ques>
```

Any one have an idea about how to achieve this?
I am a newbie and all suggestions and different approaches will be welcomed. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this line

```
<ques [card_title]="'Xyz'" [card_text]="'What is Time'" 
                  [items] = "{{items}}"
```

should be like this

```
//items array in you ts file 
items:string[] = ['google','stack','overflow']";

//template 
<ques [card_title]="'Xyz'" [card_text]="'What is Time'" 
                  [items] = "items"
```

no need of `{{items}}` as you are already having `[]`which is for inputting value from ts file variable